# How to exclude wwwroot folder from an ASP.NET 5 project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How to exclude the **wwwroot** folder from an ASP.NET 5 project, so the Visual Studio wont track this folder?

[image]

Comment: Do you have *any* static files?

Comment: Define what you mean with *track*

Comment: I have static files in it which is generated through GULP. I can build the application and regenerate them - the build script can drop the files in that folder. The problem with **wwwroot** is that Visual Studio keeps monitoring this folder and the IDE UI keeps freezing.

Comment: in an ASP.NET 5 project, VS will monitor ALL folders and watch for code changes that it compiles on the fly with Roslyn. wwwroot is meant to hold the output of your Gulp tasks, or any other non-code files.

Comment: Regarding ` The problem with wwwroot is that Visual Studio keeps monitoring this folder and the IDE UI keeps freezing`...i would suggest to file an issue at http://github.com/aspnet/tooling with the appropriate details

Answer (score 0):

To exclude this folder, go into the `project.json` file and make sure it is listed in the `exclude` section as listed below:

```
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ]
```

In a newly created ASP.NET 5 web project, this file will be added for you automatically and should already have this setting configured.